# Why do $S_x$ and $S_y$ flip up/down spin states but $S_z$ does not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, quantum-spin, hilbert-space

By using the notation $S\lvert s,m_s\rangle$, such that $\bigl\lvert\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\bigr\rangle=\lvert+\rangle$ and $\bigl\lvert\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\bigr\rangle=\lvert-\rangle$ we can obtain following the eigenvalue equation for the components of the spin vector:
$$\begin{align}
S_x\lvert\pm\rangle&=\frac{\hbar}{2}\lvert\mp\rangle \\
S_y\lvert\pm\rangle&=\pm i\frac{\hbar}{2}\lvert\mp\rangle \\
S_z\lvert\pm\rangle&=\pm\frac{\hbar}{2}\lvert\pm\rangle
\end{align}$$
However, I am struggling to interpret the result. If we consider the $x$ and $y$ component of spin, then there seems to be flipping of the state function, but it's not the same for the $z$-component. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *chose* the $\lvert \pm \rangle$ to be an eigenvector of $S_z$ with eigenvalue $\pm\frac{1}{2}$ - that's what the $m_s$ is: The eigenvalue of the state w.r.t. the $z$-spin.

Since $S_x$ and $S_y$ do not commute with $S_z$, $\lvert \pm \rangle$ is *not* an eigenvector of them, hence the state cannot stay the same after they are applied to it.

That the spin is precisely *flipped* comes from the form of the commutation relations
$$ [S_i,S_j] = \mathrm{i}\epsilon_{ijk}S_k$$
and you can see that the spin is flipped by evaluating $S_z$ on $S_x\lvert \pm \rangle$ and $S_y\lvert \pm \rangle$.

Comment: why we did not choose ∣±⟩ to be an eigen vector of $S_x$ or $S_y$, I am sorry, but I am still struggling to grasp the answer.

Comment: @RoshanShrestha: You can as well choose it to be an eigenvector of any of those, or an eigenvector of the spin about any other axis. There's nothing distinguishing a special direction. You just need to pick *some* direction to talk about whether the spin is "up" or "down" compared to that direction, and we conventionally call that direction $z$.

Comment: Thanks, Can we physically interpret the above result as in Stern Gerlach Experiment ?